# How to keep row index after running predict_proba() in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, indexing, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have created a logistic regression model to predict acceptance rate of a campaign, where 0 = not accepted and 1 = accepted. Now, I need to put together three specific columns: `person_id`, the actual acceptance `score` (1 or 0), and the output from sklearn's `predict_proba()`.

Both `person_id` and its respective actual acceptance `score` I can get from the test set, so that is solved. However, if I want to merge the output from `predict_proba()` with `person_id` and `score` using their row index, then I have an issue. This is because `predict_proba()` resets the index. So, I cannot guarantee that if I were to concatenate it with the `person_id` and acceptance `score`, they would match its respective row. These are my questions:

1. Is there any way I can return the `predict_proba()` keeping the original row index from X_test? Below is the line of code for predict_proba() on the X_test set.

   ```
   df_proba = pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], columns=['proba'])
   ```
2. Does `predict_proba()` maintain row order despite reseting the index? Therefore, I could simply concatenate by column (axis=1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predict_proba()` method does not shuffle the data. The row index of your X_test is maintained after you apply the aforementioned method. In other words, the first entry of predictions corresponds to the first row of X_test. You can simply concatenate the `person_id`, `score` and `prediction`.